# How shall I use `docker rm -v`?

Tags: docker

Manpage of `docker rm` says

> **Remove a container and its volumes**
>
> ```
> $ docker rm -v redis
> redis
> ```
>
> This command will remove the container and **any volumes associated with
>   it**. Note that **if a volume was specified with a name**, it will not
>   be removed.

What does it mean by "a volume was specified with a name"? Is such a volume not a volume associated with the container to be removed?

> **Remove a container and selectively remove volumes**
>
> ```
> $ docker create -v awesome:/foo -v /bar --name hello redis
> hello
> $ docker rm -v hello
> ```
>
> In this example, **the volume for  /foo  will remain intact, but the
>   volume for  /bar  will be removed**. The same behavior holds for
>   volumes inherited with  --volumes-from .

Why "the volume for  /foo  will remain intact, but the volume for  /bar  will be removed"?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [the Docker documentation on volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) for background information, and in particular [its description of volume removal](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#remove-volumes).

> What does it mean by “a volume was specified with a name”? Is such a volume not a volume associated with the container to be removed?

It means a volume with its own name, mounted in the container using `-v name:path` or a `--mount` option. Such volumes are expected to be managed separately from any container (even when they’re created along with a container). They aren’t removed along with a container when volume removal is requested along with container removal, they need to be removed separately.

> Why “the volume for `/foo` will remain intact, but the volume for `/bar` will be removed”?

Because `/foo` is a named volume (`awesome`), so it is managed separately, whereas `/bar` is an anonymous volume, with no expectation of usefulness beyond the lifetime of the container it’s associated with.

Answer (score 2):

`docker rm -v` takes care named volumes are not deleted by mistake. Anonymous volumes may be used as a temporary storage but named volumes are expected to persist longer.

To delete named volumes as in above example: `docker volume rm awesome`